# Carregar table view com ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx

Estou a tentar carregar um table view com o resultado de uma query. O resultado da query é enviado para uma  ObservableList que depois é chamado no controlador.

Não obtenho qualquer erro mas também não apresenta qualquer resultado.
Será que alguém me pode ajudar a encontrar o caminho correto?
Código no controlador

```
public class HomeController implements Initializable {   
@FXML
private TableView prova;

@FXML
private TableColumn colId;
@FXML
private TableColumn colTipo;
@FXML
private TableColumn colProva;
@FXML
private TableColumn colData;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {        
        ObservableList<Prova> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Prova(1, "aaa", "aaa", "bbb"),
                new Prova(2, "bb", "bb", "bbb"),
                new Prova(3, "cc", "cc", "cc")
        );
        prova.getItems().setAll(list);
       // prova.getItems().addAll(list);  Tambem não Trabalha       
    try {
        OprationsOnDB.loadTableProva().forEach((tab) -> {
            //itemIdCol.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory((String) tab));
            System.out.println("Stuff with " + tab.toString());
        });     
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Código FXML

```
<TableView fx:id="prova" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
  <columns>
    <TableColumn fx:id="colId" text="#" prefWidth="100"/>
    <TableColumnfx:id="colLocal"text="Local" prefWidth="100"/>
    <TableColumn fx:id="colProva" text="Prova" prefWidth="200"/>
    <TableColumnfx:id="colData" text="Data" prefWidth="200"/>
 </columns>
</TableView>
```

Comment: Alguém me ajuda por favor!

Answer (score 1):

Você deve definir a que classe pertence a tabela e o mesmo para as colunas, ficaria deste jeito:

```
private TableView<\Prova> prova;
private TableColumn<\Prova, String> colID;
```

Comment: Julio a outra resposta também é sua? Estou vendo que não tem muito diferença entre elas.

Comment: pode usar a primeira

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazendo isto:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Prova> prova;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Prova, ?> colId;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Prova, ?> colTipo;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Prova, ?> colProva;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Prova, ?> colData;
```

**Depois de prencher os dados no ObservableList, para cada coluna declarada:**

```
colId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Prova, Integer>("codigo"));
```